# Tarfile recursively opens in windows, but not in Linux [Python]

Tags: python

I have a Python program which extracts a zip file. The zip file looks like this:

```
a.zip
  |
  |
  --- b.tar.gz
  .     |
  .     |
  .     --- c.tar
```

Here is my code:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("a.zip", 'r') as zipRef:
    with zipRef.open("b.tar.gz") as x:
        x_filedata = io.BytesIO(x.read())
        with tarfile.open(fileobj=x_filedata) as tarRef:
            tarFiles = tarRef.getmembers()
            for fileInTar in tarFiles:
                print(fileInTar)
```

In Windows, this code recursively opens `c.tar` too and prints the contents of `c.tar` file. But in Centos, it prints `c.tar`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Without access to your code, we can't say what you are doing wrong. Please review the guidance for providing a [mre]

Comment: I can't repro on CentOS 8. `tar zcf /tmp/b.tar.gz /etc/machine-id` and `zip -j /tmp/a.zip /tmp/b.tar.gz` created a file which I can extract just fine with your code (after adding the missing `import` statements)

Comment: Of course, the code prints something like `<TarInfo 'etc/machine-id' at 0x7fd5c9b91110>` and not the _contents_ of the tar member. Do you see otherwise on Windows?

Comment: There is a `c.tar` file in `b.tar.gz` also.

Comment: You mean the tar.gz contains another tar? `tar.gz` simply means a tar file which is also compressed.